# How to raise an exception in a Jinja2 macro?

Tags: python, jinja2, salt-stack

I have a macro that is used to build a local repository using [`debmirror`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Debmirror).

Here's the snippet of code:

```
{%- set gnupghome = kwargs.pop('gnupghome', '/root/.gnupg') %}
{%- set env = { 'GNUPGHOME': gnupghome } %}
keyring_import:
  cmd:
    - run
{%- if 'keyid' in kwargs and 'keyserver' in kwargs %}
    {%- set keyid = kwargs.pop('keyid') %}
    {%- set keyserver = kwargs.pop('keyserver') %}
    - name: 'gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring {{ gnupghome }}/trustedkeys.gpg --keyserver {{ keyserver }} --recv-keys {{ keyid }}'
{%- elif 'key_url' in kwargs %}
    {%- set key_url = kwargs.pop('key_url') %}
    - name: 'wget -q -O- "{{ key_url }}" | gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring {{ gnupghome }}/trustedkeys.gpg --import'
{%- endif %}
    - require:
      - pkg: wget
      - pkg: gnupg
```

At the `endif` keyword, I would like to use `else` to raise an exception, for e.g:

> Either key_url or both keyserver and keyid required.

Is it possible?

Comment: No, Jinja2 doesn't support raising exceptions. You can use python functions or filters, which can raise exceptions, but not in pure Jinja.

Answer (score 24):

Dean Serenevy's answer is elegant. Here is a shorter solution, which adds a global to jinja's environment.

```
def raise_helper(msg):
    raise Exception(msg)

env = jinja2.Environment(...
env.globals['raise'] = raise_helper
```

Then in your template:

```
{{ raise("uh oh...") }}
```

Answer (score 22):

Super quick workaround, as long as you don't mind raising a `ZeroDivisionError`:

Insert an `{{ 0/0 }}` wherever you want to raise an exception.

Comment: cause this because it is so simple. Thanks

Comment: so, I never give kudos to anyone, for anything, ever.. this is so damn clever, that I am jealous. hats off

Comment: or just call `raise()` which will raise an UndefinedError as it's not (normally) defined

Answer (score 14):

This can be handled in an extension. From https://github.com/duelafn/python-jinja2-apci

```
# FROM: https://github.com/duelafn/python-jinja2-apci/blob/master/jinja2_apci/error.py
from jinja2 import nodes
from jinja2.ext import Extension
from jinja2.exceptions import TemplateRuntimeError

class RaiseExtension(Extension):
    # This is our keyword(s):
    tags = set(['raise'])

    # See also: jinja2.parser.parse_include()
    def parse(self, parser):
        # the first token is the token that started the tag. In our case we
        # only listen to "raise" so this will be a name token with
        # "raise" as value. We get the line number so that we can give
        # that line number to the nodes we insert.
        lineno = next(parser.stream).lineno

        # Extract the message from the template
        message_node = parser.parse_expression()

        return nodes.CallBlock(
            self.call_method('_raise', [message_node], lineno=lineno),
            [], [], [], lineno=lineno
        )

    def _raise(self, msg, caller):
        raise TemplateRuntimeError(msg)
```

Pass the extension to your Environment: `jinja2.Environment(... extensions=[RaiseExtension])` then use it in your template:

```
{%- if 'keyid' in kwargs and 'keyserver' in kwargs %}
    ...
{%- else %}
    {% raise "Either key_url or both keyserver and keyid required." %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 10):

Insert a `{{ "My error explained here"/0 }}` expression. e.g.

```
{% if not required_parameter %}
{{ "required_parameter must be defined."/0 }}
{% endif %}
```

(builds on zsero's answer of 0/0)

Comment: this doesn't really provide a useful error -- for me it generates the error text: 
""" unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int' """

Answer (score 7):

If this is being done from Ansible, Ansible adds the [mandatory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#forcing-variables-to-be-defined) filter to Jinja, which can be used to do this:

```
{{ ('OK text' if condition_ok) | mandatory('Text of error message') }}
```

gives the failure:

```
fatal: [hostname]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Text of error message"}
```

(Replace `condition_ok` with the check that you need to make; `'OK text'` can be just `''`.)

Answer (score 6):

I also wanted to throw an exception with an error message from within a jinja2 template, but **without** any external dependencies (globals / extensions). I ended up with this macro:

```
{% macro abort(error) %}
    {{ None['[ERROR] ' ~ error][0] }}
{% endmacro %}
```

To use:

```
{{ abort("Either key_url or both keyserver and keyid required.") }}
```

Which gives a stack trace with this exception:

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'None' has no attribute '[ERROR] Either key_url or both keyserver and keyid required.'
```

Answer (score 4):

Another quick hack that prints a given value:

```
{% include 'error: ' ~ value_to_print %}
```

Result:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: error: abc
```